# PigUnit: add .pigbootup file

Tags: java, testing, junit, apache-pig

Is there a way to add a .pigbootup file to pigunit?
Because I want my script to use the local jars for testing and the jars located on amazon for production. So my idea was to use a .pigbootup file for registering my jars.

Any help is appreciated.

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

For people who are interested, here is how I solved it:

Don't create any of the files (pig.properties or .pigbootup), this will create them for you.

```
//Create properties file and register our jars
String pigProps = "src/test/resources/pig.properties";
String bootupPath = "src/test/resources/.pigbootup";
File propertyFile = new File(pigProps);
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(propertyFile));
out.println("pig.load.default.statements=" + bootupPath);
out.close();

File bootupFile = new File(bootupPath);
out = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter(bootupFile));
out.println("REGISTER 'src/test/resources/Custom.jar';");
out.println("REGISTER 'src/test/resources/datafu.jar';");
out.println("REGISTER 'src/test/resources/piggybank.jar';");
out.close();
```